# How do I parse HTML which includes named ISO-8859-1 entities with Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing, xhtml

I summarize:  minidom appears not to like 8859 named entities; what's an appropriate resolution?

Here's code which illustrates my situation:

```
sample = """
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Un ejemplo</h1>
      <p>Me llamo Juan Fulano y Hern&aacute;ndez.</p>
    </body>
  </html>
"""
sample2 = sample.replace("&aacute;", "&#225;")

import xml.dom.minidom

dom2 = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(sample2)
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(sample)
```

Briefly:  when the HTML includes 'á' and similar, expressed as named entities, minidom complains

```
... xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: undefined entity ...
```

How should I respond?  Do I

- Replace named entities with corresponding literal constants?

  Use a parser other than minidom?  Which?

  Somehow (with an encoding assignment?) convince minidom that these named entities are cool?

*Not* feasible is to convince the author of the (X)HTML to eschew named entities.

Comment: there are many, many previous answers to this question and its ilk, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676872/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python-using-standard-libraries

Comment: Thank you, ekhumoro; I was so dull that I didn't recognize the customer really is in an HTML situation, and his labeling it XML was just noise I should have ignored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xml.dom.minidom` is an XML parser, not an HTML parser. Therefore, it doesn't know any HTML entities (only those which are common to both XML and HTML: `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&apos;`).

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Thanks, Tim Pietzcker:  your reply is (extraordinarily!) quick, accurate, and close to what I need.  As it happens, the data with which I'm working is *advertised* as XML; over the longer term, I'm going to need to research how to reconcile minidom's idea of the pertinent DTD with that of the data's author.  In the meantime, though, I want you to know that your words are helpful:  while I'm plenty familiar with BeautifulSoup, your analysis didn't occur to me, and I didn't even think to try it in this situation.  You leave me considerably better than when I started.