# experiencing difficulty parsing a web page

Tags: python, html, json, parsing

I had downloaded a web page and saved it in the html format. I wanted to parse and obtain the values of "fullname", "memberHeadline", "numberOfConnections", etc. I tried using BeautifulSoup in Python, but it is not working. I also tried

```
>>> import json
>>> encoded_data = json.loads(f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
     encoded_data = json.loads(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I am not clear on what the format of the file is. copied below is the content of the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <html lang="en" class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <html lang="en" class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7 os-win">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8]>
            <html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8 os-win">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 9]>
                <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lte9 os-win">
                <![endif]-->
                <!--[if gt IE 9]>
                    <html lang="en" class="os-win">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
                        <html lang="en" class="os-win">
                        <!--<![endif]-->

                        <head>
                            <meta name="lnkd-track-json-lib" content="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=2jds9coeh4w78ed9wblscv68v-eo3jgzogk6v7maxgg86f4u27d&amp;fc=2">
                            <meta name="lnkd-track-lib" content="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=eo3jgzogk6v7maxgg86f4u27d&amp;fc=2">
                            <meta name="treeID" content="yGlqHfV7FxMQvJqjACsAAA==">
                            <meta name="appName" content="profile">
                            <meta name="lnkd-track-error" content="/lite/ua/error?csrfToken=ajax%3A1584468784299534813&amp;goback=%2Enpv_131506997_*1_*1_NAME*4SEARCH_9ikF_*1_en*4US_*1_*1_*1_123452511375704499972_1_63_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1">
                            <script src="http://static.licdn.com:80/scds/common/u/lib/fizzy/fz-1.3.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                fs.config({
                                    "failureRedirect": "http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/",
                                    "uniEscape": true,
                                    "xhrHeaders": {
                                        "X-FS-Origin-Request": "/profile/view?id=131506997&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=9ikF&locale=en_US&srchid=123452511375704499972&srchindex=1&srchtotal=63&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A123452511375704499972%2CVSRPtargetId%3A131506997%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary",
                                        "X-FS-Page-Id": "nprofile-view"
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=8swqmpmjehppqzovz8zzfvv9g-aef5jooigi7oiyblwlouo8z90-7tqheyb1qchwa8dejl8nvz7zd-10q339fub5b718xk0pv9lzhpl&amp;fc=2"></script>
                            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
                            <meta name="pageImpressionID" content="3b47eb21-1db4-42c1-9d00-43b2918c4099">
                            <meta name="pageKey" content="nprofile_v2_view_fs">
                            <meta name="analyticsURL" content="/analytics/noauthtracker">
                            <link rel="openid.server" href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/openid/authorize">
                            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/img/icon/apple-touch-icon.png">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=3bifs78lai5i0ndyj1ew7316e-c8kkvmvykvq2ncgxoqb13d2by-cphg8n6ehozk6lgpbb36za2ap-2it1to3q1pt5evainys9ta07p-4uu2pkz5u0jch61r2nhpyyrn8-7poavrvxlvh0irzkbnoyoginp-4om4nn3a2z730xs82d78xj3be-3t9ar1pajet97hzt9uou74qbb-ct4kfyj4tquup0bvqhttvymms-58ujm6g9r0a3ok6mpq7cs25gn-9zbbsrdszts09by60it4vuo3q-8ti9u6z5f55pestwbmte40d9-5730os2tf3iaiql5c8fukzd2u-cxff0g818hf3ks7dzixd4lqcq-6ramlbadr9lh7v5r7vuc6t4ld-e5frmcn40t833k1adjvwkoyjq&amp;fc=2">
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=dfoaudjrk6rbf82f45bz5crwi-62og8s54488owngg0s7escdit-c8ha6zrgpgcni7poa5ctye7il-3ufb745s29q1ovtbq6htt6rwh-51dv6schthjydhvcv6rxvospp-e9rsfv7b5gx0bk0tln31dx3sq-2r5gveucqe4lsolc3n0oljsn1-8v2hz0euzy8m1tk5d6tfrn6j-d4jr8g8vadmx9i5wz2z6ck3pb-1wfd86vm2f60y6uu5isrw94q-ddqoqtn6xcqi8i0y3tsrdl533-81wr8bey9cjjn6rhvbv530cap-6iw3fvg61uute6gxy89acxi5d-5sxnyeselbctwpry658s2lkew-4c6mz6u5rinti47gswwanj74j-5eec9p1vamr86uabn13sngx92-6oxtrh5eu6olunu39xzqgp10i-cdr0psywot2inbx54hmajga3p-anaxa6l712w7m4gp8089vyb5m-3h7320kwlnqtbngzm67z2annq-80vg9koywz84zoon9sjflbru0-8cwe3ciy81r59l0q3usztbt2r-1na957r12xyfe317uma5pn9mc-57sur4cj634ll9tk38imgvc6g-8v6o0480wy5u6j7f3sh92hzxo-9puf8y7tgjvse2oqtgkdb4wcj-c9pibx8dlmicbwjh48g12z6bl-12xp8e6pputw80p9fcpzyy9m0-3xjyji4eyuzpbppt3cssr1oko-34nej6plgotmo4hbnvjthteuu-4nw8tqsdbe61ig2l9faf3qdi9&amp;fc=2"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                LI.define('UrlPackage');
                                LI.UrlPackage.containerCore = ["http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=d7z5zqt26qe7ht91f8494hqx5&fc=2"]
                                [0];
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/js/scds-hashes.js"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                LI.JSContentBasePath = "http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?v=build-2000_1_28557-prod&fc=2";
                                LI.CSSContentBasePath = "http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?v=build-2000_1_28557-prod&fc=2";
                                LI.injectRelayHtmlUrl = "http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/lib/inject/0.4.2/relay.html";
                                LI.injectRelaySwfUrl = "http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/lib/inject/0.4.2/relay.swf";
                                LI.comboBaseUrl = "http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?v=build-2000_1_28557-prod&fc=2";
                                LI.staticUrlHashEnabled = "true";
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=c19zsujfl1pg46iqy33ubhqc5-eu97293ov7e2qciy9zn7fyg55-4n3akxbgwkyp3he1eeb136xxq-aq8gt7g4x1o11fxmypuv7vfkb-8kh6sn7nciobs2crbqunav09q-6m96aslgoubdqpnadnimrxsuk&amp;fc=2"></script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                document.cookie = 'lang="v=2&lang=en-us"; domain=linkedin.com; version=0; path=/;';
                            </script>
                            <title>xyz abc | LinkedIn</title>
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/css?h=449dtfu96optpu75y189filyn-4lrmst05cep59hjxopm4xrj84-depvqaeschv5p2381431jub3f-ae142xp1b9qwrvanr8q32v931&amp;fc=2">
                            <!--[if gte IE 9]>
                                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/favicon_ie9.ico">
                            <![endif]-->
                            <!--[if (!IE)|(lt IE 9)]>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/favicon_v3.ico">
    <![endif]-->
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=6rei9ktvfprzc38327x3gt0u3-c61ck8yq8xgf9ji3h55bmaux8-e7bh8bocljccs3kjl5f03uw8j&amp;fc=2"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.c.lnkd.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=bqzk7a8ih1jk3hy30mnqy9jxb-39gmm0e77xjrikdpkxed7aywi-d228wbwzysn60azozcfg7gzoa&amp;fc=2"></script>"ind_lookup":"Financial Services","isShared":false,"logoId":"/p/3/000/10d/1c1/3af8941.png"},{"link_biz":"/company/axis\u002dmutual\u002dfund?trk=prof\u002dfollowing\u002dcompany\u002dlogo","universalName":"axis\u002dmutual\u002dfund","id":565614,"logo":"http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/media/p/2/000/036/30a/1bf5734.png","canonicalName":"Axis Mutual Fund","biz_follow":"/company/follow/submit?id=565614&csrfToken=ajax%3A1584468784299534813&goback=%2Enpv_131506997_*1_*1_NAME*4SEARCH_9ikF_*1_en*4US_*1_*1_*1_123452511375704499972_1_63_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1","ind_lookup":"Financial Services","isShared":false,"logoId":"/p/2/000/036/30a/1bf5734.png"},{"link_biz":"/company/uti\u002dmf?trk=prof\u002dfollowing\u002dcompany\u002dlogo","universalName":"uti\u002dmf","id":467803,"logo":"http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/02f/205/35eec6b.png","canonicalName":"UTI MF","biz_follow":"/company/follow/submit?id=467803&csrfToken=ajax%3A1584468784299534813&goback=%2Enpv_131506997_*1_*1_NAME*4SEARCH_9ikF_*1_en*4US_*1_*1_*1_123452511375704499972_1_63_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1","ind_lookup":"Financial Services","isShared":false,"logoId":"/p/3/000/02f/205/35eec6b.png"},{"link_biz":"/company/investment\u002ddata\u002dservices?trk=prof\u002dfollowing\u002dcompany\u002dlogo","universalName":"investment\u002ddata\u002dservices","id":92139,"logo":"http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/0ad/3d0/32f42f2.png","canonicalName":"Investment Data Services","biz_follow":"/company/follow/submit?id=92139&csrfToken=ajax%3A1584468784299534813&goback=%2Enpv_131506997_*1_*1_NAME*4SEARCH_9ikF_*1_en*4US_*1_*1_*1_123452511375704499972_1_63_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1","ind_lookup":"Financial Services","isShared":false,"logoId":"/p/3/000/0ad/3d0/32f42f2.png"}],"i18n_news":"News","lix_profile_showChannels":"control","i18n_unfollow":"Unfollow","isFollowing":true}},"BasicInfo":{"empty":{},"upsell":{"deferImg":true,"visible":true},"basic_info":{"showTopCardDetail":true,"visible":true,"phoneticname":"","i18n__Industry":"Industry","industry_pivot":"/search?search=&industry=43&sortCriteria=R&keepFacets=true&trk=prof\u002d0\u002dovw\u002dindustry","find_others_region":"Find other members in Mumbai Area, India","headline_highlight":"Executive at L&amp;T Mutual Fund","i18n__find_others_in_industry":"Find other members in this industry","i18n_Edit":"Edit","location_highlight":"<strong class=\ "highlight\">Mumbai Area, India</strong>","deferImg":true,"industry_highlight":"Financial Services","industryID":43,"memberHeadline":"Executive at L&T Mutual Fund","i18n__Location":"Location","memberID":131506997,"location_pivot":"/search?search=&sortCriteria=R&keepFacets=true&facet_G=in%3A7150&trk=prof\u002d0\u002dovw\u002dlocation","fmt_location":"Mumbai Area, India","fullname":"xyz abc"}}`
```

Comment: That's part of an html file.  You need the entire file, and you should use Beautifulsoup to parse it.  It's not a JSON file, which is why you get that error.  What's the Beautifulsoup code you tried?

Comment: You are interacting with a page generated by javascript. You need a lib like selenuim.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML file. You can tell because it starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` (in fact, that means it's HTML5).

The reason you can't load it with `json` is because it's not `json`. The exception you get is expected, and your code should likely handle it, because in general passing a file of the wrong type is the sort of thing that happens.

You might like to use `lxml`, possibly with the `beautifulsoup` backend, to parse this.

Comment: lxml is totally the way to go. Though I would personally recommend the html module more highly than the beautifulsoup library for performance reasons.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Quite. Unless I'm mistaken, beautifulsoup is more robust, though.

Comment: I've heard that espoused, but I've never actually encountered a place where that mattered. In my experience if the html is broken enough that it would be useful, the browser corrected it while rendering.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Yes, but if you're processing it in your code, you don't want to have to deal with the errors yourself, surely?

Answer (score 0):

The header is the doctype for HTML5 (this feature is similar of XHTML). Different of XHML, you don't really need to close some tags but in this case it seems more like a "hidden iframe streaming" technique, where the page is getting loading forever.

About the parsing, I would recommend the answers in about "parsing malformed html" ->
[How to parse malformed HTML in python, using standard libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676872/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python-using-standard-libraries)

Regards
Luan