# Parsing HTML page containing & using Python

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, elementtree

I am trying to parse HTML page in python using urllib2 and ElementTree and I am facing trouble  parsing the HTML. Webpage contains "&" within quoted string but ElementTree throws parseError for lines containing &

Script:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://eciresults.nic.in/ConstituencywiseU011.htm'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Content-type': 'text/xml'})
r = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
htmlpage=ET.fromstring(r)
```

This throws following error in Python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1282, in XML
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1624, in feed
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1488, in _raiseerror
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 676, column 73
```

Error corresponds to following line

```
<input type="hidden" id="HdnFldAndamanNicobar" value="1,Andaman & Nicobar Islands;" />
```

Looks like when HTML page is read, & sign is not parsed as `&amp;` in variable r

I tried to parse using htmlTreeParse using R program  and "&" gets converted to `&amp;` properly.

Let me know if I am missing anything in urllib2

EDIT : I replaced "&" to `&amp;` but line 904 contains < sign within javascript which throws same error. There should be a better option rather than replacing characters.

```
LINE:904    for (i = 0; i < strac.length - 1; i++) {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `xml.etree.ElementTree` is an `XML` parser. It does not handle HTML entities out of the box. `&` is [an illegal thing to have inside the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840981/are-characters-or-allowed-in-xml) and this is why it is failing.

Get yourself going with a real specialized `HTML` parser, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://eciresults.nic.in/ConstituencywiseU011.htm'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
>>> soup.find('td').text.strip()
u'ELECTION COMMISSION OF INDIA'
```

See also:

- [How to parse malformed HTML in python, using standard libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676872/how-to-parse-malformed-html-in-python-using-standard-libraries)

Comment: Thanks. Are there any option that can be specified in urllib2 request so that  these conversions happen

Comment: @Manuel I don't think there is anything like this in `urllib2`. `urllib2` does the job of getting the page. Handling HTML entities is a job for a parser.